# Lifecycle of a POST action in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have these two actions:

```
[Get]
public IActionResult Modify(int id) {}

[Post]
public IActionResult Modify(int id, Form form){}
```

The user request the document. He modify it and save his modification. The POST action is executed then he is redirected to the GET action again so he can keep editing. From the research I've have done, I seem to be using a Post/Redirect/Get pattern.

My problem arise when there are blocking validations during the post action. Since the document hasn't been saved, I can't redirect to the GET action. Can I return my view in the POST action or does it goes againts the pattern?

Comment: If you return the view from ether of the post actions the route will be different from the get action, try both to see the difference, but I would recommend returning to the get page since that's where the from starts. otherwise this is a very opinionated answer.

Comment: I will clarify the question but I still intend to redirect to the modify once it is created. I know the route will change but since the user should no longer create a form, I think it's ok.

Comment: "Best practice" questions are generally considered off-topic:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Comment: Thank you, I will reformulate my question and keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: I don't see how this is opinionated at all.  The purpose of the PRG Pattern is simply to prevent the re-submission of a previous post if the user refreshes the browser.  You, as a programmer, determine whether that is appropriate to use and when it is not.  For example, if a post is invalid, I do not redirect the user.  There may be circumstances when a refresh and asking the user to submit again will be valid.  I know this because that's the requirements sometimes.  It's tool just like any other pattern, you use it with it's appropriate.